# Calculate percentage of common values between a column and a list, based on categories in another column with R

Tags: r, dataframe, overlap

I am quite stuck with this exercise, so I would really appreciate if somebody could shed some light onto it. I have a **dataframe** with two columns, as in the following example:

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| 100100 | rs-1 |
| 100100 | rs1597782599 |
| 100100 | rs1603359091 |
| 100100 | rs1603359205 |
| 100300 | rs372751467 |
| 100300 | rs3732413 |
| 100300 | rs387907031 |
| 100300 | rs9852894 |
| 100800 | rs-1 |
| 100800 | rs121913114 |
| 100800 | rs144995231 |
| 100800 | rs17883400 |
| 100800 | rs761325047 |
| 101000 | rs1060503667 |
| 101000 | rs1060503668 |
| 101000 | rs1060503669 |
| 101000 | rs1060503670 |
| 101000 | rs1060503671 |

And a **list of rs codes** as in the `dataset$V2`.

What I am trying to get is the percentage of common rs codes between column 2 and the list, but grouping by the codes in `dataset$V1`. E.g.:

| V1 | Common % |
| --- | --- |
| 100100 | 25% |
| 100300 | 40% |
| 100800 | 50% |
| 101000 | 100% |

I tried several options, but with no success. For example, I am trying with `tidyverse` `group_by(dataframe$V1)` option, but I am not really sure how to concatenate the estimation of the common percentage.

Thank you all so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess at `dataframe2`' structure:

```r
set.seed(42)
dataframe2 <- dataframe[sample(nrow(dataframe), size=10),]
dataframe2
#        V1           V2
# 17 101000 rs1060503670
# 5  100300  rs372751467
# 1  100100         rs-1
# 9  100800         rs-1
# 10 100800  rs121913114
# 4  100100 rs1603359205
# 2  100100 rs1597782599
# 14 101000 rs1060503667
# 16 101000 rs1060503669
# 8  100300    rs9852894
```

### base R

```r
tmp <- merge(transform(dataframe2, orig=TRUE), dataframe, by = c("V1", "V2"), all = TRUE)

aggregate(orig ~ V1, data = tmp, FUN = function(z) {100 * sum(!is.na(z)) / length(z);}, na.action = NULL)
#       V1 orig
# 1 100100   75
# 2 100300   50
# 3 100800   40
# 4 101000   60
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dataframe2 %>%
  mutate(orig = TRUE) %>%
  full_join(., dataframe, by = c("V1", "V2")) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarize(common = 100 * sum(!is.na(orig)) / n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#       V1 common
#    <int>  <dbl>
# 1 100100     75
# 2 100300     50
# 3 100800     40
# 4 101000     60
```

Comment: This solution completely helped me. Thanks a lot!